# Image Editor with accurate dimensions

Tags: ipad, applications, image-editing

I've recently purchased an iPad and I'm looking for an app that will allow me to resize and crop photos to specific dimensions.

There are plenty of editing apps that I have seen but nothing seems to have the ability to edit to set dimensions.

For example I have a photo that is 800x600 and I need to edit it to be 660x300.

Comment: Now in 2017, 5 years later, there are probably some other apps capable of this. Any other answers? I was going to ask the same question myself until I found this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program called [Everclipper Plus](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/everclipper-plus-photo-resizing/id416457410?mt=8) would appear to meet your requirements, however this is not a full featured Image Editor, just purely one that provides a set of correctional tools.

From the blurb

> Features
>
> - Resizing. You can resize a photo on it's length scale of one to ten. You can see the result of resizing before save it.
> - Customizable sets of resizing sizes. You can make presets of resizing sizes as you like.
> - Cropping. You can crop a photo at any position and to any size.
> - Customizable sets of cropping sizes. You can make presets of cropping sizes as you like.

Comment: Sounds perfect, don't need the functionality of editing other than cropping and resizing, will try this app out this evening and let you know.

Comment: Great app, does exactly what I need it too, only downside is that it's an iPhone app but I'll live with that to gain the functionality that I need.

Answer (score 1):

[Crop-Size](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id742846888) offers cropping and resizing to specific dimensions on iPhone and iPad. This is possible via manual input or size presets. It also has correction tool that helps to adjust cropping size and position with accuracy of 1 pixel.